# Настройка таймаута POST запроса в OkHttp3

Tags: java, android, okhttp

В приложении для отправки запроса на сервер использую `okhttp`.

При запросе кодирую изображения выбранные пользователем в `Base64`.

Запрос выполняется дольше обычного и при выборе тяжелого изображения `okhttp` ожидает примерно минуту и выдает `onFail()` метод Callback-а.

Как сделать так, чтобы запрос не прерывался до окончание запроса?

Запрос:

```
//  Не обращайте внимание на синтаксис 
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequistBody formBody = new Requist.Builder().add("img",ConvertBitmap).build();
Requist req = new Requist.Builder().url("http://myWebSite.com").post(formBody).build();
Response r = client.newCall(req).execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример настройки таймаута:

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

Если в качестве таймаута передавать `0`, тогда не будет таймаута: ["A value of 0 means no timeout"](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java#L527)

---

Вы можете задать достаточно [большой таймаут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html), например в 10 минут: `.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

Comment: большое спасибо